# How to stop execution of a method and return in main class in scala?

Tags: scala, return

I'm still pretty new to Scala Language and for this I do not know how to stop execution of a method and return in main class to continue execution of the code;
I tried to use `return` and `sys.exit()` commands, but nothing, or maybe I wrong something.

This is main class

```
class Main (
[...]
val a = new CheckCriterion(a,b,c,d)
[...]
)
```

in Main class I run CheckCriterion class;

This is a part of code of CheckCriterion :

```
class CheckCriterion{
[...]
val checkCritRDD: RDD[(String, Int)] = new CheckCriterion(criterionRDD: RDD[(String, String)], op: String, compare: Array[String], criteriaType: String).CheckRDD()
  [...]
}
```

I want that if `checkCritRDD` is empty,

1) the execution of the code below is stopped

2) return to Main class

3) execute remaining code in Main class

Can help me?

Comment: As the error says, you are not inside a method so there is nothing to return from. Your code executes in the constructor body of `CheckCriterion`. You could make that a method instead (`object CheckCriterion { def apply(): Unit = { val check = ... if (check ... ) return }}`

Comment: The class     CheckCriterion  executes many functions and runs a method like 'CheckCriterion' ; I can't add a method in this class, so there is another way to stop the code under 'val checkCritRDD' , exit from the class 'CheckCriterion'  and return to the mail class?

Comment: You need to post a self-contained example, otherwise it's impossible to see what you are trying to do here. You cannot return from a `val` definition, you can only assign a different value such as `None` or `null`.